# postfix multiple IP SMTP banner

Tags: linux, postfix, smtp, email-server

I've installed postfix `2.11.3` and we have multiple IP addresses on our server which we want to host two domains, isolated and running on their own IPs.

```
domain1  unix -       -       n       -       -       smtp
   -o smtp_bind_address=1.1.1.1
   -o smtp_helo_name=mail.abc.com
   -o syslog_name=postfix-mail.abc.com

domain2  unix -       -       n       -       -       smtp
   -o smtp_bind_address=2.2.2.2
   -o smtp_helo_name=mail.xyz.com
   -o syslog_name=postfix-mail.xyz.com
```

Following transporter `/etc/postfix/sender_transport` also defined in `main.cf`:

```
@abc.com    domain1:
@xyz.com    domain2:
```

After restarting postfix, it stopped listening on port `25`:

```
[root@postfix-2.11.3]# telnet 1.1.1.1 25
Trying 1.1.1.1...
telnet: connect to address 1.1.1.1: Connection refused
```

But if I use following line in `master.cf` it listen on 25 and i can see banner if i telnet:

```
1.1.1.1:smtp inet  n - n - - smtpd -o myhostname=mail.abc.com 
2.2.2.2:smtp inet  n - n - - smtpd -o myhostname=mail.xyz.com
```

But I want to tell my mail server when you send out email use specific domain just like `sender_transport`

What i am doing wrong?

## Notes:

I have removed following line from `master.cf` and replaced with above domain1 and domain2:

```
smtp      inet  n       -       n       -       -       smtpd
```

Comment: Any error lines in `maillog` after you restart postfix??

Comment: Yes, restarted and nothing in logs, I have very good knowledge of `qmail` mail and mail services so i have checked all basic stuff, I am new with postfix so bit confused, I think we need `1.1.1.1:smtp` line without that it is not going to listen on `25` port, Now i have put both entries `domain1/2` with `ipaddress:smtp` now it is listening on both IPs. but issue is when i am sending email from xyz.com it is default using `1.1.1.1` IP that means it is not looking into `sender_transport` file.

Comment: This is what i am trying to do but it didn't work https://wied.it/blog/sender-dependent-default-transport-maps-with-postfix-the-easy-way.html

Comment: Sorry guys! i have figured out what was the issue, we need both entries. `x.x.x.x:smtp` and `domain1/2` before i was using either domain1 or smtp but i got the point.. sorry for hassle

Answer (score 16, accepted):

## Solution - Postfix version 2.7 or above required:

/etc/postfix/master.cf

```
#smtp      inet  n       -       n       -       -       smtpd
127.0.0.1:smtp inet  n     -       n       -       -       smtpd
      -o syslog_name=postfix-localhost
      -o smtp_helo_name=localhost
      -o smtp_bind_address=127.0.0.1
      -o myhostname=localhost

65.xxx.xxx.100:smtp inet  n     -       n       -       -       smtpd
      -o syslog_name=postfix-mail.abc.com
      -o smtp_helo_name=mail.abc.com
      -o smtp_bind_address=65.xxx.xxx.100
      -o myhostname=mail.abc.com

65.xxx.xxx.200:smtp inet  n     -       n       -       -       smtpd
      -o syslog_name=postfix-mail.xyz.com
      -o smtp_helo_name=mail.zyx.com
      -o smtp_bind_address=65.xxx.xxx.200
      -o myhostname=mail.xyz.com

abc-out  unix -       -       n       -       -       smtp
   -o smtp_bind_address=65.xxx.xxx.100
   -o smtp_helo_name=mail.abc.com
   -o syslog_name=postfix-mail.abc.com

xyz-out  unix -       -       n       -       -       smtp
   -o smtp_bind_address=65.xxx.xxx.200
   -o smtp_helo_name=mail.xyz.com
   -o syslog_name=postfix-mail.xyz.com
```

/etc/postfix/main.cf

```
sender_dependent_default_transport_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/sender_transport
```

/etc/postfix/sender_transport

```
# Use source IP - 65.xxx.xxx.100
@abc.com                abc-out:
@example.com            abc-out:

# Use source IP - 65.xxx.xxx.200 
@xyz.com                xyz-out:
```

Run command to generate hash db

```
postmap hash:/etc/postfix/sender_transport
```

Restart/Reload postfix

```
service postfix reload
```

Testing

```
[root@localhost ~]# telnet 65.xxx.xxx.200 25
Trying 65.xxx.xxx.200...
Connected to 65.xxx.xxx.200.
Escape character is '^]'.
220 mail.xyz.com ESMTP Postfix
```

Sending email test

```
[root@localhost ~]# telnet localhost 25
Trying ::1...
telnet: connect to address ::1: Connection refused
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
220 localhost ESMTP Postfix
helo localhost
250 localhost
mail from: spatel@xyz.com
250 2.1.0 Ok
rcpt to: spatel@gmail.com
250 2.1.5 Ok
data
354 End data with <CR><LF>.<CR><LF>
Hello world!
.
250 2.0.0 Ok: queued as 93E708207BA
```

Got to gmail Inbox > Show Original

```
Delivered-To: spatel@gmail.com
Received: by 10.xxx.xxx.xxx with SMTP id w64csp782609qgd;
        Tue, 9 Dec 2014 09:35:57 -0800 (PST)
X-Received: by 10.xxx.xxx.xxx with SMTP id o28mr4132552yha.168.1418146557180;
        Tue, 09 Dec 2014 09:35:57 -0800 (PST)
Return-Path: <spatel@xyz.com>
Received: from mail.xyz.com ([65.xxx.xxx.200])
        by mx.google.com with ESMTPS id n10si743294ykc.114.2014.12.09.09.35.56
        for <spatel@gmail.com>
        (version=TLSv1.2 cipher=ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 bits=128/128);
        Tue, 09 Dec 2014 09:35:56 -0800 (PST)
...
...
Message-Id: <20141209173720.93E708207BA@localhost.localdomain>
Date: Tue,  9 Dec 2014 12:37:11 -0500 (EST)
From: spatel@xyz.com

Hello world!
```

Voila!! see it used `65.xxx.xxx.200` IP address to sent out email..

```
Received: from mail.xyz.com ([65.xxx.xxx.200])
```

Comment: I'm trying the same but hitting a configuration conflict with the default directives Ubuntu uses in master.cf. There is a conflicting smtp listener for the main IP address. How do you deactivate the default SMTP service? This is also for a system using amavis.

Comment: @soze hash on begin mean comment line #smtp      inet  n

Comment: Is there a way to set options like `smtp_bind_address` directly from `transport_maps` / a MySQL table instead of having them hardcoded at the `master.cf` file?