# Postfix: Set custom SMTP Banner based on address used to access server

Tags: postfix, smtp, hostname, smtpd

The Postfix parameter `smtpd_banner` sets the text of a server's SMTP greeting banner. The default setting is:

```
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name
```

My mail server has several unique IP addresses assigned to it, one per domain for which it hosts email. In other words, something like this:

- `203.0.113.1` for `example1.com`
- `203.0.113.2` for `example2.com`
- `203.0.113.3` for `example3.com`

A sending server wanting to send email to `user@example2.com` would access the server using `example2.com` and `203.0.113.2`.

I would like the SMTP banner to reflect the domain that is being used to access the mail server. For example, someone accessing the server using `example2.com` or `203.0.113.2` should see the SMTP Banner:

```
example2.com ESMTP Postfix
```

Anyone accessing using the other domains or IP addresses should see the respective domain printed in the place of `$myhostname` in the default setting.

**Is this possible with Postfix, preferably without running multiple instances of Postfix, and if so, how?**

Comment: I have discovered Exim has `$smtp_active_hostname`. Maybe I will switch one day.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The parameter can only be set once, so you will not be able to dynamically change it, however you can override it in Postfix's `master.cf` file as explained in [this SF answer](https://serverfault.com/a/650326/163830).

The only way (that I know of) is for you to run several Postfix instances as you suggested, however for the sake of a SMTP banner, I personally think this is overkill.