# postfix multiple smtp banner with smtp relay like mandrill, mailjet

Tags: email, postfix, smtp, email-server, smtpd

I followed the guide to setup postfix with multiple SMTP banners and I am really happy. It works wonderfull. guide: [postfix multiple IP SMTP banner](https://serverfault.com/questions/650057/postfix-multiple-ip-smtp-banner)

The same thing I try to use with a transactional mailer for my campaigns on a different domain.

I defined at master.cf an own sections

```
mjet-out     unix -       -       y       -       -       smtp
   -o relayhost=[in-v3.mailjet.com]:587
   -o smtp_sasl_auth_enable=yes
   -o smtp_sasl_security_options=noanonymous
   -o smtp_sasl_password_maps=hash:/etc/postfix/sasl_passwd
   -o smtp_use_tls=yes
```

and in my:

```
sender_dependent_default_transport_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/sender_transport
```

I added the line:

```
/@my-domain\.ch$/    mjet-out:
```

I expected that the mail is forwarded propperly to the other smtp banner that is not. Any ideas ?

I don't like to define it in the main.cf otherwise everything goes out through this gateway which I'd like to avoid.

For any hints and help I'd be thankful.

with kind regards,

Tamer

Answer (score 1):

I could have solved it myself.

I put the entire configuation inside the main.cf file:

```
smtp_sender_dependent_authentication = yes
sender_dependent_relayhost_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/sender_relay
smtp_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtp_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
smtp_sasl_password_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/sasl_passwd
```

sender_relay:

```
myaddress@mydomain.ch in.mailjet.com
@mydomain2.ch in.mailjet.com
```

will make use of the mail engine.

sasl_passwd:

```
@mydomain.ch providerlogin:providerpass
@mydomain2.ch providerlogin2:providerpass2
```

In this case postfix will route everything in this direction, in case the sender matches the sender_relay otherwise will make use of the existing config.

Comment: and of course a further section in the "sender_transport" is not necessary.